# jqgrid custom_func validate existing row

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, custom-function

I dont know what's wrong with my coding?

```
colModel: [
                {
                    key: true, hidden: true, name: 'Id', index: 'Id', editable: true
                }, {
                    name: 'ProjectCode',
                    index: 'ProjectCode',
                    sorttype: "text",
                    edittype: "text",
                    editable: true,
                    editrules: {
                        required: true,
                        custom: true,
                        custom_func: function (value, colName) {
                            return validateDuplicateData(value, colName);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Here is validateDuplicateData function :

```
 function validateDuplicateData(value, colName) {
        var allRowsInGrid = $('#jqgrid').jqGrid('getRowData');
        $.each(allRowsInGrid, function (k, v) {
            if (v.ProjectCode == value) {
                return [false, "Project code has been used. Please try using another code."];
            }
        });
    }
```

why the result always shows below :

MessageBox : "Custom function should return array!"

Please advice... 
Thank you..

Comment: You should exclude the value from the *current* row from testing. Could you include more details about what you do? Which editing mode and `datatype` you use? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? One can specify `custom` as callback function in free jqGrid instead of usage `custom_func`. You will get rowid as parameter, which allows easy exclude the editable row from testing.

Comment: The comment to [the commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/92e128be0c830944053a29b7a69a31db13540d08) described the options of `custom` callback in details. See [the issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/pull/184) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The function never returns true with array. It should return true at the end of function if, after looping, no duplicate data was found.